# Trying to use the OR option to search for two different REGEX (python)

Tags: python, regex

I am currently attempting to use re.search to match either the first pattern or the second pattern. When I do run the script the error I am given is the following: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

This is the statement I wrote in the script:

```
match = re.search("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"|"[0-9]{1,2}", string)
if match is None:
    exit()
```

I am looking for the search to match with an input that is either something like 255.255.255.0 or an input that is a two digit number such as 24

If possible could someone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have the extra double quotes within the regex itself. The regex should just be one single string.

I.e. instead of

```
match = re.search("[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"|"[0-9]{1,2}", string)
```

put

```
match = re.search("[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,2}", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `|` in extra quotes and use a raw string:

```
match = re.search(r"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,2}", string)
if match is None:
    exit()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help! While testing this out I realized my question may not have been 100% clear. For example let's say if I input 255.255.255.0 then it would match with the first expression or if it is a 2 digit number, then it would match with the second expression.